# what is the smallest 3-CNF possible that enforces the boolean expression: a = b + c?

Tags: boolean-algebra

What is the smallest 3-CNF system of equations possible that enforces the boolean expression: a = b + c for boolean variables a, b, c?

'Smallest' can be defined as: (1) Number of 3 CNF clauses. (2) Number of new variables introduced in the clauses.

We are interested in both cases.

Comment: What do you mean by $+$? XOR or disjunction?

Comment: disjunction....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, note that $b+c$ can be expressed as the disjunction $b\lor c$. To enforce equation, you need to express "$a$ iff $(b\lor c)$", and that can be encoded as the following CNF formula: $$ \phi = (\neg a \lor b \lor c) \wedge ((\neg b \wedge \neg c) \lor a)$$

Indeed, I used the fact that $A\to B \equiv \neg A \lor B$ and applied that twice. $\phi$ is not in CNF form, but you can simplify it to:  $$ \phi = (\neg a \lor b \lor c) \wedge (\neg b \lor a) \wedge(\neg c \lor a) $$

Note that  $\phi$ can be read as "c implies a, and b implies a, and a implies at least one of b or c". Can you prove that it is minimal?

Comment: aha. I think this works fine! thanks a lot.